# Can't add key to remote machine for user

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-ec2, interpolation

I am writing a script to add user to aws ec2 instance. Below is the shell script.

```
file=$2
user=$1
user1="ec2-user"
basekey="/home/user-home/some-folder/test.pem" 
keyfile=$3
file1=`cat /home/user-home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
for line in `cat $file`
do
    ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo useradd -m -d /home/$user $user
    ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo mkdir /home/$user/.ssh
    ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo touch /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo chmod 777 /home/$user/.ssh
    ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo chmod 777 /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    scp -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $keyfile $user1@$line:/home/$user1/ 
    sleep 10
    ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo cat /home/$user1/id_rsa.pub > /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo cat /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    echo ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo chmod 600 /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    echo ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo chown $user.$user /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    echo ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo chmod 700 /home/$user/.ssh
    echo ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo chown $user.$user /home/$user/.ssh
done
```

I am getting below error though the file present there.

```
./dev-enable.sh: line 24: /home/devuser/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
```

I can't find a way to interpolate this particular line. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Which line is actually failing? Why do you `sleep` in the middle of the script? The file `/home/devuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` clearly doesn't exist - what would you expect the script to do about that?

Comment: @l0b0 If you see I am doing a scp to ec2 instance which will take 3-4 seconds may be. So for that point of time I do not want my script to go ahead without scp operation. Actually there is a folder and file in that particular location `/home/devuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` in which the command can't write the public key, I am trying to add.

Comment: All the script operations are synchronous, so it's *impossible* to reach a line before *all* lines before it is done. You don't need to `sleep` at all.

Comment: Where are you running the script can you paste the path? And also do you have this path in your EC2 instance? /home/devuser/

Comment: @error2007s Yes I do have this path on my ec2 instance. I am running this script on my laptop. You see, I am able to create user using useradd command in first line. Then I am also able to create .ssh folder and authorized_keys file for user however I can't write pub file content into authorized_keys file. Can't figure out why.

Comment: I guess that is happening because authorized_keys file has a permission 600 on it and ec2-user does not permission to write to that file only root and devuser (as devuser is the owner) can write to that file so tweak your script appropriately.

Comment: @error2007s I tried with ownership and permission issues but its not about that. I think its more about the > sign which is causing this issue. If I put single, double or reverse quotes it is taking literal value as /home/$user/.ssh/ which I am not able to interpolate to correct value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue No such a file or Directory. I was looking at wrong part of the command. I was able to resolve it using interpolation and correct syntax of shell command. below is correct command to handle such situation.

```
ssh -i $basekey -o strictHostKeyChecking=no $user1@$line sudo bash -c "'cat > /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys'" < $file1
```

and file1 is defined as below

```
file1=/home/user-home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```